# No more access to logined user in event subscriber after update to symfony 5.2

Tags: symfony

i've updated from Symfony 4.4 to 5.2 (with installed php 7.4 on Ubuntu).

If I call

```
{{dump(app.user)}}
```

in twig file i see the logined user.

But in Session file i can't access to logined user in
my SessionConfig php file neither with the Security class nor with TokenStorageInterface.
Both is null, within the `dd()` function.

```
...
class SessionConfig implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
...
public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, TranslatorInterface $translator, Security $security, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    dd($security->getUser(), $this->user);
}
...
```

Can you help me, because i didn't the find any solution in internet until now to fix my problem.

Note: Even a downgrade to symfony 5.1 didn't solve my problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Update: 07.02.2021

```
// ...
class SessionTestConfig implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, TranslatorInterface $translator, Security $security)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->security = $security;
    }


    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->isMasterRequest()) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            if(preg_match('/^\/admin/', $request->getPathInfo())) {
              $session = $request->getSession();
              if (!$session->get('username')) {
                  // do something
              }
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered after the Traceable Firewall listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 101]],
        ];
    }
}
```

Before symfony update if no user is logined part `// do something` could be accessed when session becomes invalid.
After symfony update the call `$session->get('username')` is always null. Independent if user is logined or not.

And i don't understand why. Can you help me?

Note: If i use `$this->security->getUser()` (instead of `if(!$session->get('username')) {...}`)
this didn't also work, because the user recognition if user is null or not is only working, if i set priority to 7 or lower but this to late.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised the code worked in earlier versions.  The problem is probably due to the listener being constructed before the user is actually available.  Typically you would store the token storage instance(or the security instance) in your constructor and then pull the user from it when you actually need the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my problem description, that you can understand my concrete problem better.